# How to capture IP packets during boot time?

Tags: linux, networking, boot, network-interface

I am interested to see the first packet my system sends out during boot time. Therefore, wondering if there's a better way than using a virtual OS.

Comment: Plug it into a hub or mirrored switch port and sniff traffic with a different computer while it boots

Comment: If only I had a hub, and another computer. :(

Comment: You can activate firewall rules before putting the network interfaces up, and you can add a rule that logs all traffic sent.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a system service (script) starting before network does, which would launch a tcpdump. Depending on linux distro, this would occur either in

- init scripts (e.g. /etc/rc3.d/ assuming runlevel 3 on a 'init' driven system )
- or systemd settings (/etc/systemd/system )

Note: as I post this, I have a doubt if tcpdump command will be accepted before network is started...